# Javascript 'this' returning window instead of my object

Tags: javascript, this

I am trying to understand why this is returning Window instead of my object. Looking at my previous examples this is working. I must be missing something obvious.

```js
(function($) {
  if (typeof a === "undefined" || a === null) a = {};
  if (typeof a.b === "undefined" || a.b === null) a.b = {};
  if (typeof a.b.c === "undefined" || a.b.c === null) a.b.c = {};
  if (typeof a.b.c.d === "undefined" || a.b.c.d === null) a.b.c.d = {};
  if (typeof a.b.c.d.e === "undefined" || a.b.c.d.e === null) a.b.c.d.e = {};

  a.b.c.d.e.MyObject = {
    method1: function() {
      console.log(this); //Returning Window
    },

    method2: function() {

    }
  }
}(jQuery));
```

This is being called via eval() from another JS file.

Comment: You've not shown how you are calling `method1`. This could make all the difference...

Comment: When the page loads there is a call to a.b.c.d.e.MyObject.method1

Comment: If that's because you did something like `window.onload = a.b.c.d.e.MyObject.method1;` then that's the problem. The value of `this` is determined by the way the function is **called**, not by the way it's defined.

Comment: Mind fixing the syntax errors first? You're missing a comma after `method1`

Comment: To be more specific, it is being called via an eval() in another file

Comment: @mgoodric - Well there's your answer then ;-)

Comment: [Understand how `this` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Lee Tayor and @Pointy I found a way around my issue. Since I was able to control what was being called via the eval() call, I modified the eval to call the following:

```js
function initMyObject() {
  a.b.c.d.e.MyObject.method1();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you already have an answer but I think you should really take a look at the way JS objects are created.
If you are using eval, I would strongly recommend against it, unless you really know what you are doing.
To create an object use:

```
var MyClass = function () {
     this.attr = 'Hello World!';
}

var myObject = new MyClass(); //Remember the new!!!!
```

And methods are declared like this (do this before creating a new object):

```
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = function () {
     return this.attr;
}
```

This way the "this" will reference the object and not the scope in witch the function is been executed.
Take a good look at JS object, see [JavaScript: The Good Parts](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596517748.do) to get some good practices for working with js

Comment: I am aware about the implications of eval, unfortunately the code I am writing is integrating into an existing framework, and I am not able to modify the core product.

Comment: Tough luck. Hope the object definition helps